# Clearing a MetaClass Singleton

Tags: python, singleton, metaclass

I've created a Singleton using a MetaClass as discussed in [Method 3 of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python)

```
 class Singleton(type):
      _instances = {}
      def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
         if cls not in cls._instances:
             cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
         return cls._instances[cls]


class MySing(metaclass=Singleton): ...
```

I'd like to be able to clear the Singleton in the `setUp()` method of a `unittest.TestCase` so that each test starts with a clean Singleton.

I guess I don't really understand what this metaClass is doing because I can't get the correct incantation for a `clear()` method:

```
     def clear(self):
       try:
          del(Singleton._instances[type(self)]
       except KeyError:
          pass   #Sometimes we clear before creating
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?  My singleton is not getting cleared.

```
sing=MySing()
sing.clear()
```

The `type` call above returns `Singleton` not `MySing`.

Comment: Except for the syntax error at `del(Singleton` this code works fine. If you try `print(sing is MySing())` you'll get `False` as output.

Comment: `clear` would make more sense as a class method than an instance method.

Comment: I found my error.  My example here was not what was really in my code.  My code actually had `MySing.clear()` which is a class method and explains why `self` was different than I thought.

Comment: Do you want `_instances` to be an empty dictionary or do you just want to remove a specific item.?

Comment: Remove specific instances.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's walk through a (corrected) definition of `Singleton` and a class defined using it. I'm replacing uses of `cls` with `Singleton` where the lookup is passed through anyway.

```
 class Singleton(type):
     _instances = {}
     
     # Each of the following functions use cls instead of self
     # to emphasize that although they are instance methods of
     # Singleton, they are also *class* methods of a class defined
     # with Singleton
     def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
         if cls not in Singleton._instances:
             Singleton._instances[cls] = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
         return Singleton._instances[cls]

     def clear(cls):
         try:
             del Singleton._instances[cls]
         except KeyError:
             pass

class MySing(metaclass=Singleton):
    pass

s1 = MySing()   # First call: actually creates a new instance
s2 = MySing()   # Second call: returns the cached instance
assert s1 is s2 # Yup, they are the same
MySing.clear()  # Throw away the cached instance
s3 = MySing()   # Third call: no cached instance, so create one
assert s1 is not s3  # Yup, s3 is a distinct new instance
```

First, `_instances` is a class attribute of the metaclass, meant to map a class to a unique instance of that class.

`__call__` is an instance method of the metaclass; its purpose is to make instances of the metaclass (i.e., classes) callable. `cls` here is the class being defined, *not* the metaclass. So each time you call `MyClass()`, that converts to `Singleton.__call__(MyClass)`.

`clear` is also a instance method of the metaclass, meaning it also takes a instance of the meta class (i.e again, a class) as an argument (not an instance of the class defined with the metaclass.) This means `MyClass.clear()` is the same as `Singleton.clear(MyClass)`. (This also means you can, but probably shouldn't for clarity, write `s1.clear()`.)

The identification of metaclass instance methods with "regular" class class methods also explains why you need to use `__call__` in the meta class where you would use `__new__` in the regular class: `__new__` is special-cased as a class method without having to decorate it as such. It's slightly tricky for a metaclass to define an *instance* method for *its* instances, so we just use `__call__` (since `type.__call__` doesn't do much, if anything, beyond invoking the correct `__new__` method).

Comment: I searched for a lot of singleton good-to-go code snippets, this was the best for me. Thanks, suggested changing except Key Error: pass because continue should give a syntax error

Answer (score -2):

I see three useful test cases for this metaclass at first glance.

- Test whether a single class creation works properly.
- Test whether no new class is created after the initial one.
- Test whether multiple classes can use this metaclass in conjunction.

**All of these tests can be achieved without a "reset" button**. After which you'll have covered most of your bases. (I might have forgotten one).

Simply create a few different TestClasses that use this metaclass and check their Id's and types.

Comment: This really doesn't get to the question at hand.  The code being tested uses a singleton run once per invocation, so we're testing that each invocation works properly in each test.  That means clearing the Singleton before running each test.

Comment: This does, though, point to the fact that there is probably a better way to structure your tests that don't require a `Singleton` metaclass in the first place, such as defining a single instance of a class from `setupModule` instead of "recreating" the object in each test case, to use `unittest` as an example.

Comment: I would argue a method `.clear()` **available on every instance** that resets your Singleton is a much greater risk than a less-than-perfect test setting.

Comment: Without providing a solution for unit testing the singleton class, you aren't answering the real first question, which is how to test classes with metaclass=Singleton. Without that, most unit tests will fail because single instance of a class with metaclass=Singleton will have unpredictable state.